# Matlab is slow when using user defined function with calculation in GPU

Tags: performance, matlab, function, gpu

When I run the code shown below, the tic/toc pair inside the function shows it takes very short time (<< 1sec) to go through all the lines. However, it actually takes around 2.3secs to get the outputs!!! I use the tic/toc pair to measure the time.

```
tic

rnn.v = 11;
rnn.h = 101;
rnn.o = 7;
rnn.h_init = randn(1,rnn.h,'gpuArray');
rnn.W_vh = randn(rnn.v,rnn.h,'gpuArray');
rnn.W_hh = randn(rnn.h,rnn.h,'gpuArray');
rnn.W_ho = randn(rnn.h,rnn.o,'gpuArray');

inData.V = randn(10000,11,100,'gpuArray');
inData.TimeSteps =100;
inData.BatchSize = 10000;

[H,OX] = forward_pass(rnn, inData)
toc
```

All the matrices in rnn, and inData are gpuArray, so all the calculation are carried out in GPU. The outputs are also gpuArray.

```
function [H,OX] = forward_pass(rnn, inData)
        tic;
        %initial hidden state values
        H_init = gpuArray(repmat(rnn.h_init,[inData.BatchSize,1]));

        %initialize state H
        H = zeros(inData.BatchSize, rnn.h, inData.TimeSteps,'gpuArray');

        %initialize OX (which is H * Who)
        OX = zeros(inData.BatchSize, rnn.o, inData.TimeSteps,'gpuArray');

        for t = 1 : inData.TimeSteps

            if t == 1
                HX_t = H_init * rnn.W_hh... 
                        + inData.V(:,:,t) * rnn.W_vh;
            else
                HX_t = H(:,:,(t-1)) * rnn.W_hh... 
                        + inData.V(:,:,t) * rnn.W_vh;
            end

            H(:,:,t) = tanh(HX_t);
            OX(:,:,t) = H(:,:,t) * rnn.W_ho;


        end

        toc;
    end
```

Normally, if you use gather() function, it will be slow. I didn't use the gather() function to transfer the outputs to workspace, I don't know why it is still so slow. It looks like the last line "end" takes more than 2secs.

Anyone knows how to accelerate the function call?

Comment: inData.V is a 10000x11x100 gpuArray. rnn.W_vh is a 11x101 gpuArray, rnn.W_ho is a 101x7 gpuArray, H is a 10000x101x100 gpuArray, OX is a 10000x7x100 gpuArray.

Comment: rnn.v = 11; rnn.h = 101; rnn.o = 7; rnn.hid_nonlin = Tanh; rnn.h_init = 1x101 gpuArray; inData.BatchSize = 10000; inData.TimeSteps =100; Thanks Divakar!

Comment: Sorry, my first time on this site. I have edit my question so you can copy & paste and run the code on your local machine. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, for proper benchmarking you do need to use `gather` either inside the function call or afterwards. In the former case, you would have a non-gpu output from the function call and in the latter case, a gpu-based datatype would be the output. Now, back to your problem, you are using very few `TimeSteps` and as such any optimization that you might try out won't reflect in a huge manner. Here's an optimized version that will show increased performance as you increase `Timesteps` -

```
function [H,OX] = forward_pass(rnn, inData)

H = zeros(inData.BatchSize, rnn.h, inData.TimeSteps,'gpuArray');

T = reshape(permute(inData.V,[1 3 2]),[],size(inData.V,2))*rnn.W_vh;
H(:,:,1) = tanh(bsxfun(@plus,rnn.h_init * rnn.W_hh,T(1:size(inData.V,1),:)));

for t = 2 : inData.TimeSteps
    H(:,:,t) = tanh( H(:,:,(t-1))*rnn.W_hh + ...
        T((t-1)*size(inData.V,1)+1: t*size(inData.V,1),:));
end

A = reshape(permute(H,[1 3 2]),[],size(H,2))*rnn.W_ho;
OX = permute(reshape(A,size(H,1),size(A,1)/size(H,1),[]),[1 3 2]);

return;
```

---

## Benchmarking

**Test Case #1**

Parameters

```
rnn.v = 11;
rnn.h = 5;
rnn.o = 7;
inData.TimeSteps = 10000;
inData.BatchSize = 10;
```

Results

```
---- Original Code :
Elapsed time is 5.678876 seconds.
---- Modified Code :
Elapsed time is 3.821059 seconds.
```

**Test Case #2**

Parameters

```
inData.TimeSteps = 50000; (rest are same as in Test Case #1)
```

Results

```
---- Original Code :
Elapsed time is 28.392290 seconds.
---- Modified Code :
Elapsed time is 19.031776 seconds.
```

*Please note that these are tested on GTX 750 Ti.*